# Getting Started with HDF5

Tags: hdf5

I'm trying to use HDF5 in a C# .NET application on a 32 bit Win XP machine. I am a total newbie to this HDF5 stuff.

I downloaded the Windows binary distribution, "HDF5-1.8.7_win_x86.zip" from
http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5.html. 
I can't really follow the instructions in the "INSTALL_Windows.txt" because I don't have 'windows' directory under the downloaded stuff, from where the instructions ask me to run a 'copy_hdf.bat' file!

My intention as of now, is to store some simple text & numeric data using HDF5. Can someone please suggest how do I get about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download `HDF5-1.8.7_x86_static.zip` instead.

The instructions in the package you downloaded were probably a bit outdated. This one should work.